# bootstrap datetimepicker dp.change not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the code

```
                                <td nowrap>
                                    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="MeetingToEdit_Id" name="MeetingToEdit.Id" type="hidden" value="33" />
                                    <input id="MeetingToEdit_SubjectId" name="MeetingToEdit.SubjectId" type="hidden" value="7f0912f9-4d7f-48a1-8290-acd66fd937f0" />
                                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The FirstName field is required." id="MeetingToEdit_FirstName" name="MeetingToEdit.FirstName" type="hidden" value="R" />
                                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The LastName field is required." id="MeetingToEdit_LastName" name="MeetingToEdit.LastName" type="hidden" value="Fa" />
                                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="MeetingToEdit_Email" name="MeetingToEdit.Email" type="hidden" value="rukidmanff@msn.com" />
                                    <input id="MeetingToEdit_Company" name="MeetingToEdit.Company" type="hidden" value="Australia" />
                                    <input id="MeetingToEdit_HostFirstName" name="MeetingToEdit.HostFirstName" type="hidden" value="Neer" />
                                    <input id="MeetingToEdit_HostLastName" name="MeetingToEdit.HostLastName" type="hidden" value="Admin" />
                                    <input id="MeetingToEdit_HostEmail" name="MeetingToEdit.HostEmail" type="hidden" value="admin@admin.com" />
                                    <input id="MeetingToEdit_HostMobile" name="MeetingToEdit.HostMobile" type="hidden" value="+6968723" />
                                    <script>
                                        $('#MeetingToEdit_StartTime').on('dp.change', function (selected) {
                                            var endDate2 = $('#MeetingToEdit_EndTime');
                                            endDate2.data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment(selected.date));
                                            endDate2.data("DateTimePicker").date(moment(selected.date).add(1, "hour"));
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Update" />
                                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="/Home/ReinviteVisitor?visitorId=7f0912f9-4d7f-48a1-8290-acd66fd937f0&amp;email=rukiman%40msn.com">Cancel</a>
                                </td>
```

When the page loads I get this error:
Javascript runtime error: Unable to get property 'minDate' of undefined or null reference this is for the line: ndDate2.data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment(selected.date));

Also as a side note the datetimepicker is not displayed in the correct position. As the more rows there are on the table, the higher the datetimerpicker is positioned instead of appearing as part of the textfield it was opened from.

Comment: Which DateTimePicker library do you use?
Where is the DateTimePicker instanced?

Comment: This in in MVC I am using the bootstrap datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

Your DateTimePicker instance seems to not be stored in the data property of your input.

You should try something like that:

```
var endDate2 = $('#MeetingToEdit_EndTime');
endDate2.minDate(moment(selected.date));
endDate2.date(moment(selected.date).add(1, "hour"));
```

Comment: ok but funny thing is this bit of code is working elsewhere. Only difference here is that I am preloading the textfields with a date while in the other area where it works I don't preload a date.

Comment: I will have to try this tomorrow at work. But see comment above if it makes any difference